# android volley Json

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Как я могу получить данные из запроса используя volley в android?

JSON

```
[
   {
      "name":"Spain",
      "capital":[
         "Madrid"
      ],
      "alphaCode":"ES",
      "phoneCodes":[
         "34"
      ]
}
]
```

java

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("name");
                                           infoTxt.setText(jsonObject.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

все нашел

```
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
```